# How is a software able to read a network file faster than it appears to be possible?

Tags: performance, operating-systems, file-handling

Note this is a general, conceptual question about performance optimization.  motivated by the following real-world case.

I have a file on a Windows network drive that has a 100Mbps limt; it is a binary file and is 165MB.

My local machine has software on it specifically designed to manipulate this file format, and when opened in that software takes less than a second to display all the information. When monitoring the Task Manager during this split second, the process for the software shows:

- 13% Network (@ 26.4 Mbps briefly)
- 08% CPU (@ 1.2% briefly)

Since the format is known, I wrote a Python script to parse it and the fastest that I can do while using the `struct` module is roughly 15-17 seconds. During this time, CPU  usage for the Python process doesn't change, but Network usage reaches 94% (@ 82 Mbps on average).

What could a software be doing that its able to fully read the file so fast, yet I'm maximizing the network bandwidth and it takes me much longer?

Comment: Does it really display *all* the information? Or is it just very fast as displaying *the information it needs*? Unless the program is cheating and caching things on your machine, the only way I can see it doing what it does is reading only a subset of the file.

Comment: @SebastianRedl It displays all the information. Its geometry information, and its all displayed. I thought it might cache, so I had a user on another system load it on theirs and it was just as fast the first time for them.

Comment: @datta: I am skeptical it shows **all** the information. 165MB is enough data for a 24bit bitmap about 7500 pixels square. I highly doubt your "geometry information" display is *anywhere* close to as dense. You're not seeing all the data, it's only showing some of it, and showing more detailed information on request.

Comment: @whatsisname Its an ESRI shapefile containing 36000 rectangles; all 36000 show up in less than a second on the display. Perhaps of note, the file contains a lot of information that it doesn't need to display (for example before each geometry grouping is a 48 byte header; but there is useful information there).

Comment: Assuming those rectangles use `doubles` for their points, that's only 1.1 to 2MB of data or so for just the rectangles. There is a lot of extra information in that extra 163MB that isn't being displayed right away.

Comment: @whatsisname Correct. So for 36000 shapes thats (5 * 16 * 36000) or 2.88MB. Perhaps the software is just reading the points and skipping everything else? I don't see how it would do that because some of that information is critical.

Comment: @datta: or, it skips some of that information until it's requested and then it just reads it on demand. Try this, load the file, wait a second for the shapes to appear, then unplug your network connection. Then try doing all your work. See if the data is all there.

Comment: I don't know a ton about windows networking, but maybe its using compression?

Comment: how many megabytes of memory does your computer have?

Comment: The values displayed in task manager over the course of one second are meaningless. Short peaks in resource use will not register, what you see is an average over several seconds in the past. You can tell by the update frequency which isn't that high. This is OK, you would not be able to process more frequent updates and the monitoring itself would be a waste of resources. And you would not notice such short bursts as a degradation in responsiveness either. I suspect the application is caching, try changing the file content in between tests.

Comment: @datta: is it an arbitrary shapefile, or is it a specific one which may be optimized by holding the same geometry information in different level of details? Using different LODs is a standard  optimization technique to support different zoom levels very quickly.

Comment: @DocBrown It is an arbitrary one which does not leverage LOD.

Comment: @MartinMaat If it were caching, then why is the same result achieved on another users system that has never looked at the file?

Comment: @datta It would help if you would tell us what you know, like what the software does. Apparently you know exactly what it does because you wrote an alternative program. Here's another suspicion: the fast program does not read every byte in the file but takes samples and works with those. It opens a stream on the file and reads every 100th record or so.

Comment: @MartinMaat The program simply parses the file spec, thats all it does with these files. It is quite likely that its only sampling the bytes it needs, but I would've thought system overhead of calls to `seek` and the like would be expensive.

Comment: @datta Seek is expensive but setting the read position in the stream is not. One can jump in anywhere in a large file and start reading there (a couple of bytes) and jump again. Note that "simply parses the file spec" does not mean anything to an outsider, regardless what the person knows about computer science.

Comment: @MartinMaat How could somebody read a different position in stream without first seeking to that position? The file specification was written by the same people who developed the software. It contains geometry data for polygons, lines and points. The software reads this file and displays that geometry as their intended shapes on the screen to the user (for example, counties in a state).

Comment: @datta I had the wrong idea about Seek, apparently that is the same as changing the read position. This is cheap, for a disk device it is like dropping the needle of your record player a couple of songs further into the groove. You do not have to follow the groove to the new position. It is basically addressable memory.

Comment: @datta Aha, it displays geographical data. Could it be reading just the data in your view port?

Comment: @MartinMaat I'm not sure what device is on the end where the data is stored over the network (disk or SSD). As for the data, the view port was the entire extent of the data so no data was excluding; further, all data would still need to be read to check if it was inside the view or not anyhow.

Answer (score 9):

A network of 100 [Mbps](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rate) (mega bits per seconds) conveys 12,5 MB per seconds, including payload and protocol overhead. A file of 165 MB needs at least 13,5 seconds (In fact, it would require slightly more: data has to be packed into [IP packets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet) of maximum 64KB, each having an additional 40 byte header).

So it is strictly impossible that the application can read the full data in less than a seconds.

There are several possibilities however to achieve the behaviour that you describe:

- if the file format would be extremely redundant and the server side could compress it to only 7% of it’s original size. This is very improbable.
- if the app would have read the data before (e.g. cached from previous session? or background loading?)
- if the app reads only a small part of the file (less than 12,5 MB), display immediately the partial content to the screen, and while you wonder how fast it is and start reading the content, starts reading the rest if the file in background.

The last hypothesis is by far the most probable.

Comment: That’s what would happen with a 165MB video file. All the information about the file takes very little space. Most of the 165MB is only read as you play the video.